# Is there a way of generating combinations while increasing the values?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, python-itertools, fasta

I am trying to write a program in Python that fetches FASTA sequences from a list of UniProt IDs given by the user. This is the code snippet I use for the first task (this works):

```
def fetch_sequence(uniprot_id):
 url = f'https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/{uniprot_id}.fasta'
 response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
 sequence = ''
 for line in response:
   line = line.decode('utf-8').strip()
   if not line.startswith('>'):
     sequence += line
 return sequence
```

What I am trying to do is generate FASTA files containing different combinations of the protein sequences fetched separated by a ':', for a maximum of 5000 amino acids. For example:

```
> 2xprotein1, 3xprotein2, 1xprotein3
sequence1:sequence1:sequence2:sequence2:sequence2:sequence3
```

Important details are: each of the proteins in the initial list provided by the user [UniProt1, Uniprot2, etc.] should be present at least one time in each of the generated FASTA files; if I already have a FASTA file, for example protein1:protein2:protein3, I do not want to generate its permutations, like protein2:protein1:protein3.

I tried using the itertools combination function, but it does not generate the required combinations because, of course, it just creates combinations of the initial list. I wanted to try something like this:

```
#i.e. for 4 proteins
[1, 1, 1, 1]
[2, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 2, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 2, 1]
...
```

By trying all of these combinations, I was hoping to create every combination, but now I am concerned that, if the code hits the threshold, it will exclude possibilities that would have been generated after this and still would have been below the 5000 amino acid threshold. Also, this would be a recursive approach, which slows the code down significantly.

Comment: What does `[1, 1, 1, 1]` represent in your example ?  If the numbers are identifiers of the proteins, then it would not meet the "at least one of each" condition.  If they are the number of repetitions of each of the 4 proteins, then there is some missing context in the example (how many of each).  Where would the 5000 threshold apply in that example (is it the sum of the numbers ?)

Comment: @AlainT. Hi, apologies for the confusion. The numbers in the lists I start generating from [1, 1, 1, 1] would be the number of times I insert the respective sequences in the total sequence. For example, [1:2:1:3] would give me a protein sequence that is protein1:protein2:protein2:protein3:protein4:protein4:protein4. The 5000 amino acids would be the threshold to apply to the latter sequence. So if the length of protein1:protein2:protein2:protein3:protein4:protein4:protein4 (excluding the :) is greater than 5000, the sequence should be discarded and that specific combination ignored.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a recursive generator function that progressively builds the sequence counts based on the remaining available size taking into account the minimum size of the upcoming counts.  This will only produce combinations that meet your criteria.

```
def genSequences(proteins,maxSize):
    if not proteins:
        yield []
        return
    minSize = sum(map(len,proteins))
    count = 0
    while maxSize >= minSize:
        count   += 1
        maxSize -= len(proteins[0])
        for seq in genSequences(proteins[1:],maxSize):
            yield [count]+seq
```

ouput:

```
maxSize  = 30
proteins = ["ABCD","12345","XYZ","MPPPQQQ"]

for sq in genSequences(proteins,maxSize):
    print(sq,"size:",sum(c*len(p) for c,p in zip(sq,proteins)),
                     "".join(p*c for c,p in zip(sq,proteins)))

[1, 1, 1, 1] size: 19 ABCD12345XYZMPPPQQQ
[1, 1, 1, 2] size: 26 ABCD12345XYZMPPPQQQMPPPQQQ
[1, 1, 2, 1] size: 22 ABCD12345XYZXYZMPPPQQQ
[1, 1, 2, 2] size: 29 ABCD12345XYZXYZMPPPQQQMPPPQQQ
[1, 1, 3, 1] size: 25 ABCD12345XYZXYZXYZMPPPQQQ
[1, 1, 4, 1] size: 28 ABCD12345XYZXYZXYZXYZMPPPQQQ
[1, 2, 1, 1] size: 24 ABCD1234512345XYZMPPPQQQ
[1, 2, 2, 1] size: 27 ABCD1234512345XYZXYZMPPPQQQ
[1, 2, 3, 1] size: 30 ABCD1234512345XYZXYZXYZMPPPQQQ
[1, 3, 1, 1] size: 29 ABCD123451234512345XYZMPPPQQQ
[2, 1, 1, 1] size: 23 ABCDABCD12345XYZMPPPQQQ
[2, 1, 1, 2] size: 30 ABCDABCD12345XYZMPPPQQQMPPPQQQ
[2, 1, 2, 1] size: 26 ABCDABCD12345XYZXYZMPPPQQQ
[2, 1, 3, 1] size: 29 ABCDABCD12345XYZXYZXYZMPPPQQQ
[2, 2, 1, 1] size: 28 ABCDABCD1234512345XYZMPPPQQQ
[3, 1, 1, 1] size: 27 ABCDABCDABCD12345XYZMPPPQQQ
[3, 1, 2, 1] size: 30 ABCDABCDABCD12345XYZXYZMPPPQQQ
```

If you don't need the counts, you could make the generator yield the combined sequences directly:

```
def genSequences(proteins,maxSize,seq=""):
    if not proteins:
        yield seq
        return
    minSize = sum(map(len,proteins))
    while maxSize >= minSize:
        seq     += proteins[0]
        maxSize -= len(proteins[0])
        yield from genSequences(proteins[1:],maxSize,seq)
```

...

```
for sq in genSequences(proteins,maxSize):
    print(len(sq),sq)

19 ABCD12345XYZMPPPQQQ
26 ABCD12345XYZMPPPQQQMPPPQQQ
22 ABCD12345XYZXYZMPPPQQQ
29 ABCD12345XYZXYZMPPPQQQMPPPQQQ
25 ABCD12345XYZXYZXYZMPPPQQQ
28 ABCD12345XYZXYZXYZXYZMPPPQQQ
24 ABCD1234512345XYZMPPPQQQ
27 ABCD1234512345XYZXYZMPPPQQQ
30 ABCD1234512345XYZXYZXYZMPPPQQQ
29 ABCD123451234512345XYZMPPPQQQ
23 ABCDABCD12345XYZMPPPQQQ
30 ABCDABCD12345XYZMPPPQQQMPPPQQQ
26 ABCDABCD12345XYZXYZMPPPQQQ
29 ABCDABCD12345XYZXYZXYZMPPPQQQ
28 ABCDABCD1234512345XYZMPPPQQQ
27 ABCDABCDABCD12345XYZMPPPQQQ
30 ABCDABCDABCD12345XYZXYZMPPPQQQ
```

If the performance of recursive functions is a concern, you can use an iterative approach for the generator:

```
def sequences(proteins,maxSize):
    *sizes,   = map(len,proteins)
    counts    = [1]*len(proteins)
    yield tuple(counts)
    p         = 0
    size      = sum(map(len,proteins))
    while p < len(proteins):
        if size+sizes[p] > maxSize:
            p += 1
            counts[:p] = [1]*p
            size = sum(c*s for c,s in zip(counts,sizes))
            continue
        counts[p] += 1
        size      += sizes[p]
        yield tuple(counts)
        p = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Thanks for clarifying! I used <strike>`itertools.combinations_with_replacement`</strike> `itertools.product` to generate the number of representations for each sequence instead.

```
import itertools
import urllib
import numpy as np

# Specify the UniProt IDs here
uids = [protein1, protein2, protein3, protein4]
# Fetch sequences from UniProt
seqs = [fetch_sequence(uid) for uid in uids]

# minimum no. of instances = 1
# maximum no. is infinite, or until total seq length reaches 5000
# If each sequence was represented at least once, the max no. of times is given by (5000/smallest seq length)
smallest_seq_length = min([len(s) for s in seqs])
# In this instance we have 5000 as the sequence length limit. So max times a sequence can be represented is
max_rep = int(np.ceil(5000/smallest_seq_length))
times = list(range(1,max_rep))
times = [times]*len(seqs)

seqs_combinations = []
for c in itertools.product(*times):
    # To deal with time complexity, we can safely eliminate combinations whose sum is greater than max_rep. So,
    if sum(c) <= max_rep:
        temp = []
        for ndx, i in enumerate(c):
            temp += [seqs[ndx]]*i
        seqs_combinations.append(":".join(temp))

# Eliminate sequences above threshold length
seqs_combinations = [s for s in seqs_combinations if len(s.replace(":",""))<5000]
```

`%%timeit` gives the following result for the above code using 4 protein sequences:

```
13.7 s ± 1.16 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Demo with short sequence (threshold length of 30):

```
seqs = ['THERE','WERE','DAYS']
smallest_seq_length = min([len(s) for s in seqs])
max_rep = int(np.ceil(50/smallest_seq_length))
times = list(range(1,max_rep))
times = [times]*len(seqs)

seqs_combinations = []
for c in itertools.product(*times):
    print(c)
    if sum(c) <= max_rep:
        temp = []
        for ndx, i in enumerate(c):
            temp += [seqs[ndx]]*i
        seqs_combinations.append(":".join(temp))
        
seqs_combinations = [s for s in seqs_combinations if len(s.replace(":",""))<30]
```

Here's the result:

```
['THERE:WERE:DAYS',
 'THERE:WERE:DAYS:DAYS',
 'THERE:WERE:DAYS:DAYS:DAYS',
 'THERE:WERE:DAYS:DAYS:DAYS:DAYS',
 'THERE:WERE:DAYS:DAYS:DAYS:DAYS:DAYS',
 'THERE:WERE:WERE:DAYS',
 'THERE:WERE:WERE:DAYS:DAYS',
 'THERE:WERE:WERE:DAYS:DAYS:DAYS',
 'THERE:WERE:WERE:DAYS:DAYS:DAYS:DAYS',
 'THERE:WERE:WERE:WERE:DAYS',
 'THERE:WERE:WERE:WERE:DAYS:DAYS',
 'THERE:WERE:WERE:WERE:DAYS:DAYS:DAYS',
 'THERE:WERE:WERE:WERE:WERE:DAYS',
 'THERE:WERE:WERE:WERE:WERE:DAYS:DAYS',
 'THERE:WERE:WERE:WERE:WERE:WERE:DAYS',
 'THERE:THERE:WERE:DAYS',
 'THERE:THERE:WERE:DAYS:DAYS',
 'THERE:THERE:WERE:DAYS:DAYS:DAYS',
 'THERE:THERE:WERE:WERE:DAYS',
 'THERE:THERE:WERE:WERE:DAYS:DAYS',
 'THERE:THERE:WERE:WERE:WERE:DAYS',
 'THERE:THERE:THERE:WERE:DAYS',
 'THERE:THERE:THERE:WERE:DAYS:DAYS',
 'THERE:THERE:THERE:WERE:WERE:DAYS',
 'THERE:THERE:THERE:THERE:WERE:DAYS']
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your input. This is useful, but not quite what I'm looking for. This code will generate combinations such as 'P10212:P10212:P10212' or 'P10212:P10212:P10217' (where we have the sequence in place of the UniProt ID). However, I'm looking to keep at least one copy of each protein for every combination ('P10217:P04295:P10212'), and then gradually increasing the copies, like 2x'P10217:1xP04295:3xP10212' to find all combinations of stiochiometry of this complex, as long as the final number of amino acids is < 5000. product() can be useful, but not with this usage.